# Email in cPanel cannot recieve, failure message notification

Tags: email, hosting, cpanel

I have hosting through hostgator and cPanel.  I have multiple domains.  I want to set up emails for a domain. I do so in cPanel creating a user @the-domain-name.com, giving it a password, and email is created.

It has a webmail access at www.the-domain-name.com/webmail and the username and password work to get in.  That is fine to log in that way (although I'd like to use Mac's Mail app to do so and set up to work, having difficulty there also).

The issue is that the email address can send out messages, but when I try to send a message to that email through another address, say my Gmail account, I get a "Delivery Status Notification (Failure)" email immediately after saying this:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

mynewuser@the-domain-name.com

Technical details of permanent failure: 
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain the-domain-name.com by the-domain-name.com. [104.255.196.241].

The error that the other server returned was:
550 No Such User Here"


----- Original message -----

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
       d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
       h=from:content-type:subject:message-id:date:to:mime-version;
       bh=xsx6bRmWZEpBj6Xda3lmBg1o8my3DpJB/KizTIxmSkw=;
       b=pvoW+xjEh2t0uSOsdguDhlt0ifBBYoB69jVhQsDVFV9LzIzz/hxiK7e4CIq9cgiu3a
        s3ovwDnF+612jQ2QpbjWzVAKauj2pJrgPLkX4Xd6UmLuCy/YKiVTXVCCl1wYDaIkF+b4
        uKe/JDjDG27sbpGCGaQmouTqA2I8J4tqML89BYS5bvHaPBHlo5MhFsSwFW5Tg9uiqoPV
        Ga0nqP2QaFYX4ieJeg7vjGR7t/Ifu91Xbt6Y8am0s8ktELkHKOIAm8n1KMzdpClAW1BR
        P0ujIG0WbwVQm6TwkDHN/TnXFbdKHL4/bM5Io5CBNmEvBISOtAWZf4LSXE6EmOBh4m6K
        j2VQ==
X-Received: by 10.107.135.65 with SMTP id j62mr17214703iod.47.1448046522949;
       Fri, 20 Nov 2015 11:08:42 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <myGmailAccount@gmail.com>
Received: from ?IPv6:2601:282:200:680:95c:1c6f:f086:9f28? ([2601:282:200:680:95c:1c6f:f086:9f28])
       by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id rj5sm325732igc.7.2015.11.20.11.08.41
       for <newUser@the-domain-name.com>
       (version=TLS1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA bits=128/128);
       Fri, 20 Nov 2015 11:08:42 -0800 (PST)
From: My Name <myGmailAccount@gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="Apple-Mail=_955B8E97-7DBF-44E5-931B-B41741DD943E"
Subject: test
Message-Id: <A6DE0523-0ABF-4A08-86B8-FD86342995BF@gmail.com>
Date: Fri, 20 Nov 2015 12:08:39 -0700
To: newUser@the-domain-name.com
Mime-Version: 1.0 (Mac OS X Mail 8.2 \(2104\))
X-Mailer: Apple Mail (2.2104)
```

I substituted all the real emails and domain name out with generic ones.

How can this be fixed to where I am able to both SEND and RECEIVE from the new cPanel email, and ultimately, how can I do so with Mac Mail??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Handling, sending/receiving your emails with cPanel is very easy.

As the error you get says: 550 No Such User Here , double check your email account name.

Also, check the mail log file, which on a WHM/cPanel server I think is: /var/log/exim_maillog

Of course you can always contact your host for help. The last time I had problems with my cPanel email accounts, I contacted my [host](https://rosehosting.com) and it turned out that my custom exim config file was overwritten by cPanel Exim updates.